# displays infowindow's marker without click

Tags: click, infowindow

I've tried for many hours to open automatically the infowindow's marker as soon as the map is displayed and of course without click on the marker.
I read a lot of posts but unfortunately i wasn't able to find a solution.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'onLoad', function() {infoWindow.open(map,marker);});
```

But it doesn't exists, there is no such event in the api.

Please, is somebody could help me to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentMarker, position: latlng}); infoWindow.open(map,marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"Hello World!"
  });

infowindow.open(map,marker);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```